# $BQP$ vs $NP$ in the unlikely scenario of $PH=PSPACE$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

It is known that: ${\sf BQP} \subseteq {\sf PSPACE}$ and ${\sf PH} \subseteq {\sf PSPACE}$. If tomorrow its proven that ${\sf PH} = {\sf PSPACE}$ it would also imply ${\sf BQP} \subseteq {\sf PH}$.

**Query:** Since, it is also widely believed that ${\sf NP} \not\subseteq {\sf BQP}$. So where does this leave us in terms of our understanding of ${\sf NP}$ vs ${\sf BQP}$? Even if we can't say anything with certainty, what (according to our current understanding of these two classes) would be the most likely scenario in that case?

Comment: can someone please comment?